# Would it be inconsistent to relax Coq's strict positivity checker to not look at type indices of the inductive type being defined?

Tags: coq

Writing

```
Inductive Foo : Type -> Type :=
| foo : Foo Bar
with
Bar := .
```

gives

```
Error: Non strictly positive occurrence of "Bar" in "Foo Bar".
```

I know the standard example of why strict positivity is necessary; if I have

```
Inductive Fix :=
| fFix : (Fix -> Fix) -> Fix.
```

with an eliminator

```
Fix_rect : forall (P : Fix -> Type) (v : forall f, (forall x, P (f x)) -> P (fFix f)) (f : Fix), P f
```

then I can prove absurdity with

```
Fix_rect (fun _ => False) (fun f H => H (fFix id)) (fFix id) : False
```

(Aside: Does anything go wrong if instead the eliminator is

```
Fix_rect : forall (P : Fix -> Type) (v : forall f, (forall x, P x -> P (f x)) -> P (fFix f)) (f : Fix), P f
```

?)

However, I don't see a way to make use of occurrences that appear only in indices.  Is there a way to derive a similar contradiction if non-strictly-positive occurrences are permitted in type indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a positivity issue, contrary to the error message. Rather, since you have mutual indexing, this is an inductive-inductive type (a weird "large" one at that), which Coq doesn't support.

You could try defining non-indexed types, and separate recursively defined "well-formedness" relations which encode correct indexing. E. g.

```
Inductive PreFoo : Type :=
| foo : PreFoo.

Inductive Bar : Type :=.

Fixpoint FooWf (f : PreFoo) (t : Type) : Prop :=
  match f with
  | foo => (t = Bar)
  end.

Definition Foo (t : Type) := sig (fun f => FooWf f t).
```

This is analogous to how you might have indexed intrinsic syntaxes for type theories or extrinsic presyntaxes with separate typing relations.